# Subclassed UIView to draw a polygon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a subclassed `UIView`:

```
@implementation draw2D

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPointArray:(NSArray *)pointArray
{
    DLog(@"fired");

    DLog(@"pointArray: %@", pointArray);

    DLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        DLog(@"self is valid");
        self.pointArray = pointArray;
        DLog(@"self.pointArray: %@", self.pointArray);
    }
    else {
        DLog(@"self is invalid");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    DLog(@"fired");
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);    

    DLog(@"self.pointArray: %@", self.pointArray);

    for (NSDictionary *pointInArray in self.pointArray) {
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake([[pointInArray objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue], [[pointInArray objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue]);

        DLog(@"point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));

        if ([pointInArray isEqualToDictionary:[self.pointArray objectAtIndex:0]]) {
            DLog(@"first point");
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"all other points");
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

I create the `UIView`:

```
draw2D *fieldImage = [[draw2D alloc] initWithFrame:fieldCell.fieldImage.frame andPointArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:points]];
fieldImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
fieldImage.lineColor = [UIColor redColor];
fieldImage.lineWidth = 2;
```

The issue is that in `drawRect:`, my `self.pointArray` is nil:

```
[draw2D initWithFrame:andPointArray:] | self.pointArray: (
    {
        x = 108;
        y = "105.6408";
    },
        {
        x = "27.35526";
        y = 108;
    },
        {
        x = 27;
        y = "103.5437";
    },
        {
        x = 0;
        y = "103.2816";
    },
        {
        x = "8.526316";
        y = "52.68932";
    },
        {
        x = "45.82895";
        y = "4.194175";
    },
        {
        x = "106.9342";
        y = 0;
    }
)

[draw2D drawRect:] | fired
[draw2D drawRect:] | self.pointArray: (null)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to draw a simple polygon?

EDIT:

```
@interface draw2D : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint, endPoint;
@property (nonatomic) float lineWidth;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *lineColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pointArray;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPointArray:(NSArray *)pointArray;

@end
```

EDIT 2:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        FieldInfoCell *fieldCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FieldInfoCellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Set up the cell

        //fieldImage is a draw2D UIView
        fieldCell.fieldImage = [self drawMapImageForFieldCell:fieldCell];

        DLog(@"fieldCell.fieldImage.pointArary: %@", fieldCell.fieldImage.pointArray); // Point array is still valid

        return fieldCell;
    }
}

-(draw2D *)drawMapImageForFieldCell:(FieldInfoCell *)fieldCell {
    // Creates the points array

    draw2D *fieldImage = [[draw2D alloc] initWithFrame:fieldCell.fieldImage.frame andPointArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:points]];
    fieldImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    fieldImage.lineColor = [UIColor redColor];
    fieldImage.lineWidth = 2;

    DLog(@"fieldImage.pointArary: %@", fieldImage.pointArray); //Point array is still valid

    return fieldImage;
}
```

But in `drawRect:`, pointArray is nil. /boggle

If I hard code the points into the `drawRect:` method, it draws as intended. /boggle

That log prints out the point array. Still have the issue when it gets to the `drawRect:`, its nil.  /boggle

Comment: Show us how the `pointArray` property is defined. Are you using ARC or MRC? My guess is you setup the property as `weak` instead of `strong` or `copy`.

Comment: That all looks correct. Are you positive that there is no other reference to the `pointArray` in any other code (the calling code or the `drsw2D` code? Perhaps something is clearing the array out between the call to `initWithFrame:andPointArray:` and the first call to `drawRect:`.

Comment: I guess that you are doing something wrong in your xib or storyboard file. A common error is to drag an object into a xib file, and to keep a pointer in a class that doesn't point to that object, but to a different instance.

Comment: Are you adding fieldImage to the view?

Comment: This custom drawing is being placed in a subclassed `UITableViewCell`. It is added to the cell and is connected to the property. The fieldImage is being assigned to the cell's property.

Comment: If I hard code the point array, it draws fine. Its just the pointsArray property is loosing its pointer. I create the draw2D object in a method and return, assign it to the cell's draw2D property. I check if the the point array after its assigned, and its still there.

Comment: I would guess that the view that you see in the cell is not the same as the one you create in `drawMapImageForFieldCell:`. You never add that as a subview of the cell. The one you're seeing probably comes from a xib/storyboard.

Comment: The view is assigned to the fieldImage property, then I assign the draw2D to the fieldCell.fieldImage property. If I hardcode the points, it draws in the cell fine.